# What did I do wrong in this CSS Layout?

Tags: html, css, layout

I did this layout here: http://www.2xfun.com/

It uses some css3 effects and stuff which are not supported in every browser, but if they dont work its fine.

The thing is that i really tried to keep the essentials working in old browsers.

I didnt use any negativ margins, which i know of make problems in IE 6 etc

But if i look at it in IE 6 the layout gets messy. The elements are completely garbled.

Where did I fail so terribly? I don't need an analysis of all my errors because i know its by far not perfect. But what positioning css directives are so wrong that they cause IE6 to mess everything up?

So my question is:

- What properties or combination of properties do cause such legacy incompatibility
- are there any good work arounds (css resets, javascript fixes) ?

addendum:

this is how the page looks like in ie6
[image: screen1]

and after Šime Vidas's javascript fix
[image: screen2]

and this is how it should look like and looks like in modern browsers
[image: chrome]

Comment: I feel bad for you that you have to care about IE6 :(

Comment: @xaxxon i agree with you but it should at least be possible to use! its not the design but the functionality that bothers me...

Comment: Do you have visitor stats? What's the IE6 share?

Comment: One or two of the errors validator.w3.org finds in your markup could actually cause problems. You may as well fix them all, though, of course. :)

Answer (score 3):

Everything that has position: absolute, put both top and left positions, not just top. Everything that has float AND margin, set to display: inline. That will at least fix many problems. I'd also recommend a reset styling, like Meyer's. Your code looks a bit underdefined for IE6, it's a picky one.

Comment: wow +1! nice suggestions! i didn't know the effects of combinations of theese properties. i will try that! thanks for the hint with the reset, i tried doint something like this myself but obviously i failed xD

Comment: display:inline for floated elements? Are you sure?

Comment: It may not fix everything, but if it doesn't I'd suggest adding reset styles on top of your styles first, then perhaps loading an IE only stylesheet where you set what you figure to be the problem divs (usually the one before one that "jumps") to overflow: hidden. That will show you where the problem is (often some margins etc.) Good luck.

Comment: @Sime Vidas: Never made a difference in any browser I tested if you have a float layout and does in IE6.

Answer (score 0):

Put this on the page:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

How does the page look in IE6 now?

Project homepage: http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Getting started: http://www.charlescooke.me.uk/web/lab_notes/ie7_script.html

Comment: JavaScript pwns IE straight in Trident.

Comment: looks promising, gotta reboot to windows to check ;)

Comment: unfortunately no luck :/ see added screenshots in question

Comment: @Joe Did you place it in the HEAD of the document? Also, maybe IE9.js is too much for IE6. You can try IE7.js or IE8.js. I've updated my answer with links.

Comment: yes i did (you can try at http://www.2xfun.com/?jsfix=1), will try the other scripts! thanks for providing the additional resources

Answer (score 0):

Here we go..

Add a rule to this effect to your normal stylesheet - @neXib was correct:

```
.headcontainer, .headbar {
    left:0
}
```

Without that, your site has problems even in IE7.

The above snippet, combined with adding this voodoo magic dust I created fixes the pressing IE6 issues:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<style type="text/css">
.headbar-spacer {
    width: 169px
}
.content div.right {
    padding-right: 0
}
.content h2 {
    margin: -30px 0 0 106px;
    width: 535px;
    padding: 0 0 12px 0
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

I commented out this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#username=xa-4c90156b67654829"></script>
```

It seemed to *somehow* make IE6 jump the white video container to the top of the window. So wrap that in a conditional comment if need be.

Your site looks like this with the above changes in IE6 (ignoring the low color depth of this image):
[image: win]
Much better!

**Improvements you could make:**

- Try out [DD_belatedPNG](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/) to fix your `.png` transparency issues.
- Make an image version of the CSS gradient you have on `.headbar`. At the moment, IE8 does not have a gradient. IE has support for it's own *special* kind of gradient, you might consider providing those rules (`-ms-filter`/`filter` + `gradient`?).
- Redundant point: fix `Notice: Undefined index: jsfix in /home/2xfun/html/application/views/vanilla.php on line 13`. Obviously you just put that in for testing. I recommend suppressing the PHP error by prefixing the line with `@`.
- *Kick IE6 in the face. Twice.*

Comment: haha great!  especially the very last point. thank you. why is this downvotet? gotta compensate immediately....

Comment: I'm not sure why it was down voted - anyone can see it's most definitely a useful answer. I can only guess it's because I was too specific instead of answering your actual questions: `Where did I fail so terribly? I don't need an analysis of all my errors` and `What properties or combination of properties do cause such legacy incompatibility`.