# transparent images are not transparent in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Why transparent images are not working in IE6 . i am using transparent images in my webpage its working fine in the ff but not working in IE .please help me how to fix this problem

html :

```
<img src="images/b_l.gif"
 width="32" height="32" />



css :

 body{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        font:14px;
        font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
        color:#555;
        line-height:150%;
        text-align:left;
        background-color: #FFF;

         background-image: url(images/bg.gif); 

        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        margin: 0px;
    }
```

Comment: yes you are correct but i am not using png image i am using transparent gif images

Comment: (-1) after 38 questions, you should know that "not working" is not a good way to describe a problem. And please show the HTML and CSS you are using in the context, or (even better) a live example

Comment: Transparency in GIFs should work.

Comment: *Not directly answer for your question but* you can check this service : http://www.ie6update.com/

Comment: html<img src="images/bayall.jpg" width="500" height="113" />

Comment: @Meena is there CSS related to the GIF file that defines an `opacity` or `filter: alpha`? What exactly happens, what does the image look like?

Comment: @Meena: You... could have said so...

Comment: @Meena: For your problem, I can't recall if GIF transparency works properly on `background-images` in IE6.  Have you tried it in an `<img>` tag?

Answer (score 4):

In regards to the question.

Have a look at http://fiddle.jshell.net/bGfRr/2/ with IE6 (*it is an example using transparent gifs*) and tell us if you see background colors or images in body and two boxes..

Here is a [screenshot](http://api.browsershots.org/png/original/f9/f9324cb5bd1d2e626687ede21d0d8100.png) from browsershots for the example above, and it seems to be rendering ok ..

---

In regards to other answers ..

Come on guys..

Has anyone really checked the features from an unbiased point of view ?

[image]

I am all for IE6 :P
http://www.saveie6.com/

Comment: I would downvote this, but it's amusing.  "Compatible with IT departments that fear changes" LOL

Comment: +1 for humour; -1 because it has no real relation to the OP's question :)

Answer (score 3):

IE6 does not support 24-bit transparent images (PNG transparency) automatically.  It is one of the main reasons people are trying to phase out IE6.

See: http://www.ie6nomore.com/

[image: IE6 No More]

You need to apply a Javascript fix to add an IE specific filter to fix the problem.

If you use jQuery, there is a plugin called [pngFix](http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/).

Answer (score 1):

Like others have noted, IE6 doesn't support transparent PNG images.

IE6 is almost 10 years old. That's a lifetime in technology terms. It is outdated. It should be dead, buried, extinct and exorcised to a point that noone even remembers it existed. It should be a piece of information that the world has forgotten.

So, unless you have a really good reason for worrying about IE, and that is common with very slow moving job places where intranet applications are written solely for IE6 and haven't ever been upgraded, I'd suggest you just forget that IE6 ever existed and move on to greener pastures.

IE9 is just behind the corner and many better alternatives, like Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari exist; just to name a few.

Comment: But the image in question is a GIF

Comment: @Pekka: it doesn't matter. The point of the story matters: IE6 should disappear. There will always be questions about IE6 compatibility problems and those questions are wasting everyone's energy and they are holding the web from going forward.

Comment: @darioo: While I fully agree IE6 should just die, it often [isn't incredibly hard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788105/what-did-i-do-wrong-in-this-css-layout/4789461#4789461) to fix a site to work passably IE6 if you know what you're doing.

Comment: @thirtydot: We have all been doing that for years, but the time comes when you have to exile something deliberately.  That is why Google and a number of other major providers have dropped general support for it.  My company are starting to put up upgrade browser notices when IE6 is detected.  I know the central ethos in web is "support all browsers", which I concur with, but it's not another browser, it's IE, just a massively out-of-date version.

Comment: @Orbling: You're right - I don't bother in the slightest to check IE6 support in sites I create, except in the case where I'm *specifically* asked about it - then I will fix it for more money.

Comment: @thirtydot: Do you ever try and advise clients against it?

Answer (score -1):

And if you still want to support IE6 then remember overall load time will be more and page will be bit more slow . You can use pngfix for IE but I advise to leave IE6 and do good work for others